# Почему window.outerWidth показывает больше, чем ширина экрана?

Tags: javascript

Ширина экрана 1440, а выводит 1456.

Comment: Попробуй еще self.outerWidth или self.innerWidth! Если результат тот же, значит JS не имеет к проблеме отношения!

Comment: Как вы определили ширину экрана?   
Вы ее определить могли не верно. Обычно, такая команда выдает верный результат. Т.е. установленное разрешение.

Comment: Ширина экрана мне известна. Неужели кто-то не знает какое разрешение у его экрана? Если что, можно в свойствах системы посмотреть.

Comment: Добавление self ничего не изменяет.

Comment: Если у вас Windows, то гляньте на разрешение так:  
свойства рабочего стола -> параметры -> разрешение экрана.   
У меня 1360, и все браузеры так и показывают. Т.е. все должно быть верно.

Comment: У меня нет проблемы узнать какое у меня разрешение экрана. Я его знал, когда покупал монитор, я его тысячу раз видел в Разрешение экрана. А как вы проверяете ширину в пикселях экрана? Смотрите в свойствах рабочего стола? И где в браузере посмотреть разрешение своего экрана? Я знаю, что есть разрешение 1366 на 768, и скорее всего у вас такой. Почему же у вас тогда 1360? А вопрос был про outerWidth.

Comment: Я говорил о том, что у меня разрешение экрана по ширине 1360 (НЕ 1366. Видать, настройка системы такая, что НЕ 1366). И, если открыть на весь экран браузер, то команда window.outerWidth возвращает 1360. Дальше, если я ставлю разрешение по ширине 800, то команда window.outerWidth, возвращает 800. И физическая ширина экрана тут не при чем.

Comment: Еще добавлю. Если на браузере не нажимать вверху справа кнопку, открывающую браузер на весь экран, а просто расширить браузер по всей  ширине, то команда window.outerWidth будет возвращать на несколько пикселей больше. И это размер полосы прокрутки.

Comment: Для TFT экранов разрешение системы равно физическому разрешению. Можно поставить другое, но при этом получим нечеткое изображение, т.е. возможно, но как исключение. Из существующих разрешений экранов близкое к вашему 1366 на 768, поэтому и спрашиваю, почему у вас не 1366. Может у вас ЭЛТ монитор.

Comment: Так. В марках мониторов я не разбираюсь. У меня просто ЖК, и все. в свойствах рабочего стола, у меня стоит разрешение для экрана 1360х768. Вы, я вижу, хотите копнуть глубже чем надо для решения вашего вопроса. Вот только оно вам надо?

Comment: Когда я поставил не родную ширину 1366, свойство outerWidth показывает 1382. Эти значения у меня получаются при развернутом окне браузера. Если вручную выставить ширину с точностью в пиксель по краям экрана по ширине, то свойство outerWidth показывает 1440. По поводу того, что эта команда будет возвращать на несколько пикселей больше из-за размера прокрутки, это не так. Полосы прокрутки не имеют значения, потому что их наличие или отсутствие не влияют на значение. И сами полосы прокрутки не влияют на размерные свойства объекта window.

Comment: Значит это чудеса, которых вы должны принять.

Comment: Может и чудеса. Проверял в разных браузерах. В Firefox и IE одинаково 1456, в Chrome 1440. Спасибо за ответы. А как отвечать под каждый комментарий?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Свойство window.outerWidth показывает ширину окна браузера. Можно проверить [так](http://jsfiddle.net/7KadD/6/) в каждом браузере и увидеть, то оно разное.

По всей видимости бордер окна при разворачивании не исчезает, а как-бы остается за границами экрана. Об этом косвенно говорят свойства window.screenY и window.screenY, они равны -8. Это как раз и объясняет разницу в 16 пикселей по ширине, т.е. на 16 пикселей окно больше, чем разрешение экрана. Если сделать скриншот окна и потом увеличить в графическом редакторе, то можно увидеть, что ширина границы окна в Windows 7 как раз составляет 8 пикселей. Например, в браузере Chrome свойства screenY и screenX равны 0 и outerWidth соответственно равно нормальной ширине экрана.

Comment: Почему не написано, что `innerWidth` зависит от масштаба страницы, и при уменьшении масштаба станет больше `outerWidth`?

Answer (score 1):

outerWidth показывает сколько места занято в ширину(+полоса прокрутки).
Используйте innerWidth

Comment: innerWidth показывает внутреннюю ширину области содержимого окна. Про innerWidth я знаю, не понял пока про outerWidth.

Answer (score 0):

Со свойством этим не знаком, но по всей видимости, out - переводится как "вне", видимо показывает сколько на самом деле занято места в ширину, полосы прокрутки появились?

Comment: Полосы прокрутки здесь ни при чем. Как переводится out не имеет значения.